# Fine-grained (removable) drive-type determination

Tags: windows, sd-card, usb-flash-drive, removable-storage, getdrivetype

I’m trying to write a little tool to simplify inventorying my removable media. Getting and storing a list of files on the media is simple enough, but I want to be able to catalog them according to what *type* of drive they are.

There is an [API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939.aspx) to get the drive type, but it is old and limited to floppy, CD, fixed, removable, network, and RAM. it does not give fine-grained information to determine whether a drive is a flash-drive or a memory-card (let alone even more detailed like what kind of memory-card). Even a [newer function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff551967.aspx) meant for USB drives doesn’t seem to specifically differentiate between *types* of USB media.

Is there a *reasonably* easy and reliable way (preferably C++) to determine that? (Yes, I know that some media can be modified to present as different types, but it only needs to work well enough for normal, standard media.) There is definitely *some* way to do this because Windows contains different icons for all kinds of media in `shell32.dll`, and Explorer usually uses the correct one when you plug them in.